# melodic gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.
This is the first time to use ROS for me.
I wished to do SLAM with slam_gmapping.

I am trying to build slam_gmapping since I could not find apt-get package "ros-melodic-slam-gmapping".
To build "ros-melodic-slam-gmapping", It is seems to necessary to prepare for "ros-melodic-openslam-gmapping".
But I could not find apt-get package "ros-melodic-openslam-gmapping".

I cloned the source-code of openslam_gmapping from the following.
https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_gmapping

Is this really a right(easiest) way to do SLAM?
Why couln't I find these packages in apt-get?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296170/melodic-gmapping/) by [Suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/36230/suzuki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, you have to build `gmapping` from source, as it is not [release yet (see melodic release page)](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html).

This actually goes for a lot of packages, e.g. the [ROS navigation is not yet released to melodic](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/749). For so long you have to clone from source.

Alternative would be to switch back to an older distro, e.g. ROS kinectic on Ubuntu 16.04 (also an LTS), until the releases you require have happened.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/36230/suzuki/) on 2018-07-04**:
Thank you for answering.
I misunderstood that melodic was released completely.
Thank you.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-04**:
the single packages in ROS can be release independently. Obviously, ros base has to be released first. This is the announcement that is on the homepage. Then, it is a trickle-down effect until all upstream repos are released, until a dependent repo can be released. Also many pkgs are community...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-04**:
contributions. Thus, a "complete release" is basically not possible, or rather "undefined" :-)

**Comment by [Suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/36230/suzuki/) on 2018-07-04**:
Thank you for the detailed explanation!